# How to get Query ordered by colum in linked object in Parse.com?

Tags: java, parse-platform

I have object `Invitation` and linked object `Event`
[image]
[image]

I want to get last 10 objects of `Invitation` where `Event.date` is ordered by *Descending*

I'm doing this , but it doesn't work:

```
                ParseObject parseUser = user;

                ParseQuery eventQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Event");
                eventQuery.whereLessThan("date", new Date());
                eventQuery.orderByDescending("date");
                eventQuery.setLimit(10);

                ParseQuery<ParseObject> invitationQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Invitation");
                invitationQuery.whereEqualTo("user", parseUser);
                invitationQuery.whereMatchesQuery("event", eventQuery);

                List<ParseObject> list= invitationQuery.find();
```

Comment: What does `eventQuery.whereLessThan("date", new Date());` suppose to do ??

Comment: get all events where date is Less Than current date on device

Comment: I am not sure whether you can apply two constraints on the same key, possibly not

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:
Try first query for the top 10 events. Then exec a new query on invitations where event is one of the ids you find in the first query

```
ParseQuery eventQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Event");
eventQuery.whereLessThan("date", new Date());
eventQuery.orderByDescending("date");
eventQuery.setLimit(10);
eventQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
            @Override
            public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                ArrayList<ParseObject> eventsIds = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
                if (e == null) {                    
                     for (ParseObject event : objects) {
                        eventsIds.add(ParseObject.creatWithoutData("event",event.getObjectId()));
                     }

                     ParseQuery<ParseObject> invitationQuery = ParseQuery.getQuery("Invitation");
                     invitationQuery.whereEqualTo("user", parseUser);
                     invitationQuery.whereContainedIn("event", eventIds);
                     invitationQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void done(List<ParseObject> objects, ParseException e) {
                                       //Do whatever you want with your events
                                     }
                            }
                     });
            }
        });
```

Comment: but in I include("user") also, and CustomUser also has field "date" how to handle this?

Comment: I'll first try only with one include (the event include) if it works, you can then query for this users in another query

Comment: "include" is making "fetch"... which fields in the included object that are also fetched.

Comment: and again minor change which I cast the arraylist to parse objects instead of strings, and create a parse object for each event objectId